# Running wire through built-in drywalled entertainment center

Tags: finishing

See the following picture for the entertainment center in question:
[image]

It was originally designed for 4x3 Standard Definition TVs to be placed in the bottom left alcove (partially hidden by the Corona--sorry, this was the best picture I could find for illustration).  As a result, all of the cable hookups are in that alcove instead of up on top.

I'm not concerned in particular with drilling a sufficiently-large hole through so that I can run power and coax/Ethernet.  I'm particularly interested in finding the correct pipe/tube that I can run through the hole, and then the necessary finishing parts that I can hook on each end to make it look like it was supposed to be there to begin with.

I'm planning on building a shelf to go in the lower left that will house a new surround sound receiver, xbox 1, and HTPC (the latter both pictured), so I'm considering something around 2 inches in diameter.  Thank you for any input you can provide!

Comment: Great product placement, btw :D

Comment: Hah, if you must know, I was gloating to my friends that I had taken the day off the watch some World Cup this past summer, and the Corona was just icing on the cake.

Comment: Beer and cake???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before. I use a hole saw and a PVC pipe. I use caulk to seal it in. Makes a very clean hole.

Comment: hole saw and PVC, a simple, easy route.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what exactly you're looking for, but several companies make in wall runs for tv/speaker wires. Most just assume you will be running the cables in the wall itself, and provide either blank-canvas wall plates. Some provide end point connectors in order to provide a wire 'socket' for the wall plate.

Here's a video tutorial on a simple version of this.

http://www.diypete.com/how-to-hide-tv-wires/

Answer (score 1):

These folks have a great assortment of various AV plates.

http://www.monoprice.com/Category?c_id=109&cp_id=10425

They are also sell the lowest price ethernet cables I have ever found.